# Excel Move lines from a cell to another if cell has more than one lines

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a VBA code for moving contents from one column to the other.

Condition being if the cell has more than one line, then leave the line number 1 and move the remaining lines to another column.

Please help to figure this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you stumble?

Comment: What do you mean by more than one line? Is the a hard carriage return in the cell?

Comment: I am very new to vba and not sure where to start.

Comment: If a cell has many lines lets say 4 or 5 ch10 then move everything after the first ch10 to another cell in corresponding row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some code to get you started

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Range("b4:f4").Clear                           ' sample data
    Range("b4") = "this" & vbCrLf & "is" & vbCrLf & "a" & vbCrLf & "test"

    Dim aaa As String
    aaa = Range("b4").Value

    Dim bbb As Variant
    bbb = Split(aaa, vbCrLf)                       ' split string into an array

    Range("c4").Resize(1, UBound(bbb) + 1) = bbb

End Sub
```